# Why is only one DatabaseConfig being called in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I have two DatabaseConfig.java, one in the `model1.config` package and the other in the `model2.config` package. Each have the annotations `@Configuration, @EnableTransactionManagement, @EntityScan, @EnableJPARepositories` with their respective properties set. Both configs have DataSource `@Bean`. However, when the Spring service is started, only one of the DatabaseConfigs is ever called at a time.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? Where do you have your class with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: @SpringBootApplication is in another package, outside of either of the entities

Comment: This question might need some code examples and a broader project structure to answer it. One thing you might want to add is the `@ComponentScan` Annotation to your SpringBootApplication